# Reading value sent from one controller to another using Redirect::action Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the value sent from one controller to another using Laravel framework, but the values are null. Any solution?

```
    class MovieController extends Controller
{
    public function ViewMovies()
    {
        $one = 'This is the first variable.';
        $two = 'This is the second variable';
        return Redirect::action('QualityController@ViewMovies2', ['data1'=>'one', 'data2'=>'two']);
    }
}


class QualityController extends Controller
{
    public function ViewMovies2(Request $request)
    { 
        $one = Request::get('data1');
        $two = Request::get('data2');
        echo $one;
        echo $two;
    }
}
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/','MovieController@ViewMovies');
Route::get('/','QualityController@ViewMovies2');
```

Comment: The way you have your routes set up it is impossible to access `QualityController@ViewMovies2`. They share same signature, so Laravel will see that the url matches first one and won't look further.

Comment: Once you get this fixed I suggest using GET parameters.

Comment: yes you have 2 fucntions in 2 separate controllers looking over the same url.

Comment: I was wrong though. The second (last) one will get triggered every time. Not the first one.

Comment: @devk i need two controllers in one route how can i do it please?I need like this Route::get('/','MovieController@ViewMovies');
Route::get('/','QualityController@ViewMovies2');

Comment: You can't have 2 routes with same url signature. It's impossible. Laravel will look for the last one and this is the one that will get triggered. You need to put the whole logic in the same controller if you want this to work. Of course if there's a ton of logic (I assume you will have something along the lines `if(something){ alot of logic ... return view(1);}  else { alot of logic ... return view(2); }`. I suggest moving some of this logic in some specialized classes (a quick hack would be what @Onix suggested).

Comment: @devk Thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

> fast fix

remove the second route ( `Route::get('/','QualityController@ViewMovies2');` )

and instead of this :

```
 return Redirect::action('QualityController@ViewMovies2', ['data1'=>'one', 'data2'=>'two']);
```

Use this:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\QualityController')->ViewMovies2($one, $two);
```

Your fucntoion should now be:

```
public function ViewMovies2($one $two)
    { 
        echo $one;
        echo $two;
    }
```

> EDIT:

try to import your controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\QualityController;
```

and then call it like this:

```
 $result = (new QualityController)->ViewMovies2();
 return $result;
```

Comment: this error appear : Action App\Http\Controllers\QualityController@ViewMovies2 not defined.

Comment: Thank you , but this Error appear : Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\QualityController::ViewMovies2() must be an instance of Request, none given, called in C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\Mes Projets Laraval\Annonces\app\Http\Controllers\MovieController.php on line 14 and defined @Onix

Comment: You get the error because ViewMovies2 fucntion has parameter `Request $request` so change the parameter to $one and $two . you fucntion will look like this ViewMovies2($one, $two)